# Why doesn't my before() hook in Mocha run at all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have written this following code in a file named "example.js":

```
console.log('HI HI HI HI');

describe('hooks', function() {
  console.log('before before');
  before(function() {
    console.log('ok');
  });
  console.log('after before');  
})
```

Output of the code when i run "mocha example.js" is:

```
HI HI HI HI
before before
after before
  0 passing (1ms)
```

Why didn't the "ok" get printed? I thought the before() hook runs before all the code in the describe() block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not printed because `before` is run before a test, and you don't have any.

Try add a test then it should run

```js
console.log('1');

describe('hooks', function() {
  console.log('2');
  before(function() {
    console.log('4');
  });

  console.log('3');
  it('description', function() {
    console.log('5');
    // nothing more here but still a test
  })
})
```

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know it only ran before a test. I thought it ran before any piece of code. Thanks!